# Writing a connection string when password contains special characters

Tags: python, character-encoding, sqlalchemy, connection-string

I'm using SQLalchemy for a Python project, and I want to have a tidy connection string to access my database. So for example:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@host/database')
```

The problem is my password contains a sequence of special characters that get interpreted as delimiters when I try to connect.

I realize that I could just use `engine.URL.create()` and then pass my credentials like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
    drivername="postgresql",
    username="user",
    password="p@ss",
    host="host",
    database="database",
)
print(connection_url)
# postgresql://user:p%40ss@host/database
```

But I'd much rather use a connection string if this is possible.

So to be clear, is it possible to encode my connection string, or the password part of the connection string - so that it can be properly parsed?

Comment: Can you give an example of this special char that cannot be escaped by a backslash?

Comment: missing "=" after "X6~k9?q" in connection info

Comment: that happens whether I escape it or not

Comment: @KeyboardInterrupt were you able to resolve this ? Thanks

Comment: **"I realize that I could just use `engine.URL.create()` and then pass my credentials"** - Future readers should not gloss over the fact that this really is the preferred method of creating a connection URL.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You need to URL-encode the password portion of the connect string:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
engine = create_engine("postgres://user:%s@host/database" % quote_plus("p@ss"))
```

If you look at the implementation of the class used in SQLAlchemy to represent database connection URLs (in [`sqlalchemy/engine/url.py`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py)), you can see that they use the same method to escape passwords when converting the URL instances into strings.

Comment: The part about using `unquote_plus` was apparently a bug and changed in v0.9.0 ([ref](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/7051dc5842a6e3012578b2430dbc90ceff8d7050/doc/build/changelog/migration_09.rst#the-password-portion-of-a-create_engine-no-longer-considers-the--sign-as-an-encoded-space)) - Dec 2013. Interestingly, they still quote with `quote_plus` but unquote with `unquote` so there may still be some bug lingering in there ([src](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py)).

Comment: Life saver!!! :D

Comment: `quote_plus` will cause issues if there are spaces in the password (it will encode a space as `+` which is a valid character. it should be encoded as `%20`). better use `quote`

Answer (score 45):

In Python 3.x, you need to import urllib.parse.quote:

> The urllib module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to
> urllib.request, urllib.parse, and urllib.error.

When you are trying to connect database MySQL with password which contains sequence of special characters and your python version is Python3

**user_name** is your userid for database
**database** is your database name
**your_password** password with special characters

```
 from urllib.parse import quote  
 from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
 engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user_name:%s@localhost:3306/database' % quote('your_password'))
```

Comment: does not work if you have an @ in the password.

Comment: Tanu, the quoting will change "@" to '%40'.

Answer (score 11):

### METHOD 1:

The password contains **"@"**, you can escape the "@" character using **"%40"** instead.

**BEFORE:**

```
# mssql+pymssql://username:password@databaseserver/database

mssql+pymssql://admin:admin123@10.10.10.110/dbtest
```

**AFTER:**

```
mssql+pymssql://admin:admin%40123@10.10.10.110/dbtest
```

### METHOD 2:

Encode the password using **urllib.parse.quote_plus**.

```
DATABASE_PASSWORD = "admin@123"

# to elimate the error, if the password contains special characters like '@' 
DATABASE_PASSWORD_UPDATED = urllib.parse.quote_plus(DATABASE_PASSWORD)
```

**Here is the complete code snippet :**

```
import os, sys, click, urllib
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import text

# Make sure to replace below data with your DB values
DATABASE_HOST = "10.10.10.110"
DATABASE_NAME = "dbtest"
DATABASE_USERNAME = "admin" 
DATABASE_PASSWORD = "admin@123"

app = Flask(__name__)

# to elimate the error, if the password contains special characters like '@'
# replace the DATABASE_PASSWORD with DATABASE_PASSWORD_UPDATED. 

DATABASE_PASSWORD_UPDATED = urllib.parse.quote_plus(DATABASE_PASSWORD)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql+pymssql://'+DATABASE_USERNAME+':'+DATABASE_PASSWORD_UPDATED+'@'+DATABASE_HOST+'/'+DATABASE_NAME
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True


db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```