# Cannot Connect Using SQL Alchemy Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database on my local machine. I am able to connect using MySQL Workbench, but when I try to use sqlalchemy it does not allow me to connect.

The user has the correct permissions. I can connect using MySQL bench so I know the credentials are correct.

```py
engine = create_engine('mysql://username:password!@ ***.***.***.**:3306/ceesmart')
connection = engine.connect()
```

OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, "Unknown MySQL server host ' ***.***.***.**' (2)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: Have you any special char on your password?

+info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787042/sqlalchemy-connection-string

Try with another dummy user with a simple pass just to discard.

Comment: Yes it does.  The connection works when I use local host instead of the ip so I don’t think it’s an issue with my credentials.

Comment: I don't know if it was on copying and pasting here, but you have an "space" between the "@" and the first octect. That could make the engine to resolve it as a DNS name instead of an IP, therefore, raising `Unknown (Mysql) Host`.

Comment: Will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was on copying and pasting here, but you have an "space" between the `@` and the first octect:

```
@ ***.*
 ^ here
```

That could make the engine to try to resolve it as a DNS name instead of an IP address, therefore, raising `Unknown Host` exception