# GCP Cann't deploy with install pyodbc

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyodbc

I'm try to use GCP *(Google cloud platform)* : *API Service* with python project. And this project need to use lib : pyodbc for connect to `MSSQL`.
In *localhost* it fine but when I try to deploy this project to GCP it show error like this. Can someone help me with this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine that will run the app must have **ODBC header files installed**.

To do so, you will need to deploy the app in a custom run time environment, where you install this header files before installing the requirements. For more information on how to do so you can visit [this answer on this Stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51560685/4037220).

I will also post here the process as described by [Brooks Lybrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10128987/brooks-lybrand) in Stack-overflow question mentioned above: (His solution is based on [Connect docker python to SQL server with pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405777/connect-docker-python-to-sql-server-with-pyodbc/46446438#46446438))

1. Execute `$ gcloud beta app gen-config --custom` in the same directory with your app.
2. A `Dockerfile` will be created.
3. Edit the `Dockerfile` by adding the following commands before the `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` (suggestion: add those lines after `RUN virtualenv ...` and before `# Set virtualenv environment variables ...`):

   `#Install FreeTDS and dependencies for PyODBC 
   RUN apt-get update 
   RUN apt-get install -y tdsodbc unixodbc-dev 
   RUN apt install unixodbc-bin -y 
   RUN apt-get clean -y 
   ADD odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini`
4. Create a file `odbcinst.ini` if doesn't exist already
5. Edit the file `odbcinst.ini` and add the following:

   `[FreeTDS]
   Description=FreeTDS Driver
   Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
   Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so`
6. Execute `$ gcloud app deploy` and it should deploy without any problems.

I have tested it myself and I was getting the same error. After this procedure the App was deployed without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the following error now when using the command gcloud beta app gen-config --custom:
WARNING: This command is deprecated and will soon be removed.

As an alternative, create an app.yaml file yourself using the directions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml (App Engine Flexible Environment) or https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref (App Engine Standard Environment) under the tab for your language.

To create a custom runtime, please follow the instructions at
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.gen-config) This command does not support python3.

Comment: links expire so post essentials here to maintain future rep.