# Hosting a flask app using Pyodbc on Google Cloud

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, pyodbc

I'm running a flask app on google cloud, but I'm having no luck at all using pyodbc. I initially tried

```
def googleConnection():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
            "Driver={SQL Server};"
            "Server=server;"
            "Database=dbname;"
            "UID=username;"
            "PWD=password;"
            )
    return conn
```

and I got the following error in gcloud logs:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

It's complaining that it's missing the necessary drivers. So, I ran a query to return
`pyodbc.drivers()` to see if anything was available

```
def googleConnection():
    drivers = [item for item in pyodbc.drivers()]
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
            f"Driver={drivers[-1]};"
            "Server=server;"
            "Database=dbname;"
            "UID=username;"
            "PWD=password;"
            )
    return conn
```

and it just returned an empty list, confirming no drivers, but it imports pyodbc as a package, as per my requirements file.

The DB it's trying to connect to is hosted using GCP SQL and there's no issues with auth, so it really is just missing drivers. But, I can't find any documentation on adding these in. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278707/gcp-cannt-deploy-with-install-pyodbc) that is using `gcloud -beta config` but it has since been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You must install the driver first. The ODBC driver is not pip installable.

[Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: thank you John. It's installed
`cloudshell:~ (hrace-359815)$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.1.1
UsageCount=1`

But still no change on the error when running the app

Comment: @Graham I am not sure that will work in Cloud Shell. Install locally or in a Docker container. Global installations do not persist in Cloud Shell.