# “Invalid object name” error when executing query using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, insert

I connect database with pycharm and I use sqlAlchemy. When I am trying to execute an insert query it shows the following error:

```
Invalid object name 'pfAnalytics.optPrice'
```

The error is due to the fact that it add "[" and "]" to my tables' name when I do :

```
ins = table.insert()
```

if I check the string  I see:

```
str(ins) == 'INSERT INTO [pfAnalytics.optPrice] DEFAULT VALUES'
```

instead of:

```
str(ins) == 'INSERT INTO pfAnalytics.optPrice DEFAULT VALUES'
```

my request look like this:

```
listToWrite = all.to_dict(orient='records')

metadata = sql.schema.MetaData(bind=engine,reflect=True)
table = sql.Table("pfAnalytics.optPrice", metadata)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

querydel = sql.delete("pfAnalytics.optPrice")
results = consql.execute(querydel)

consql.execute(sql.insert(table), listToWrite)
```

How to get rid of these brackets?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is tricky, it iss du to an error on SQL server. So I had to specify to to put no bracket at the begining and the end of the table's name with :

```
engine.dialect.identifier_preparer.initial_quote = ''
engine.dialect.identifier_preparer.final_quote = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue using MSSQL Server and could not seem to find an answer that would work for me. I finally discovered the problem to be in connection string for the db engine. Apparently SQLAlchemy needs the driver included in the string. This holds true if you are using a Flask app, for the URI as well as creating an engine.

An example in the Flask app:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mssql+pyodbc://username:\
password@server/database?driver=SQL+Server"
```

Similarly, in creating an engine:

```
db_string = "mssql+pyodbc://username:password@server/database?driver=SQL+Server"
engine = create_engine(db_string)
```

It seems that driver=SQL+Server is the key to making this work for me. I didn't see this on the official documentation but noticed it in another post on Stack Overflow. So credit to Praveen for this:

[Connect to MSSQL Database using Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739295/connect-to-mssql-database-using-flask-sqlalchemy)

The exact error I was getting from SQLAlchemy/pyodbc was:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name
```

Hopefully this can save someone the headache it created for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use `Database` instead of `Initial Catalog`.
Compare these two, to get the difference:

- not working one:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

- working one:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword;
```