# configure sql server in Airflow with sql_alchemy_conn

Tags: sqlalchemy, airflow

I am trying to configure the SQL server in Airflow with sql_alchemy_conn.
Airflow is running in the Linux server and DB is in windows. 
I have just started exploring Airflow, can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean MySql so for configuring mysql with your airflow you just have to create a database in your system for the respective airflow and add the below line to the **airflow.cnf** file, save it.

```
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{MYSQL_HOST}:3306/airflow
```

then do database initialising in your terminal

```
$ airflow initdb
```

Check out this [article](http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/installing-and-configuring-apache-airflow/) for a clear vission.

Comment: Thanks, I know for MySQL and PostgresSQL it a bit easy. But here I want to connect with MSSQL only.

Comment: Check this out- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038713/airflow-scheduler-with-sql-server-backend-and-pyodbc

Comment: But I'll recommend you to use either mysql or postgres:)

Comment: yes i agree, but currentluy i dont have option other than mssql.
Added below command in cfg file:
sql_alchemy_conn = mssql+pyodbc://username:pwd@dns

Throwing below error:
"Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string %s % name sql server"

Comment: I'm not sure but your connection string should be something like this ```sql_alchemy_conn = mssql+pyodbc://airflowuser#afdsqlserver76:<password>#afdsqlserver76.database.windows.net:1433/airflowdb?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server``` Are you following the format properly?

Comment: hopefully yes. with the same format, I am able to connect from python to the SQL server.
now only one doubt, as my password contains '=' symbol that is the reason I am getting Error as "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'my_conn_string".
got help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423804/writing-a-connection-string-when-password-contains-special-characters
used mssql+pyodbc://username:pwd@dns % urllib.parse.quote_plus('badpass') option as well.

Comment: Not a solution though but maybe try changing your password for an instance to check whether its causing this error or not