# SQLAlchemy PyMySQL Error, Can't Query Data From MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, pymysql

I try to connect my jupyter notebook to MySQL with SQLAlchemy, I think the connection is work but I can't read data from my database to dataframe.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import mysql.connector as sql
import pymysql

db_connection_str = 'mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost/my_db'
db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)
db_connection
```

```
import pandas as pd
query = ('SELECT * FROM my_table')
df = pd.read_sql(query,con=db_connection)
df
```

OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'word@localhost' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

How I can solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a connectivity issue, looks like when the URL gets parsed, something goes wrong as SQLAlchemy thinks `word@localhost` is the server.

You could try to use a manual [`URL`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL):

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

url = URL(
    drivername="mysql+pymysql",
    host="localhost",
    username="user",
    password="password",
    database="my_db",
)
```

Or to validate how your current url parses into a `URL` with [`make_url`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.make_url).

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import make_url

make_url('mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost/my_db')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still get the same error

Comment: Are there special characters in your password ?

Comment: yeah, there is ! and @

Comment: @Reganda then you should look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424009/17676984).