# Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect) while connect with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, sqlalchemy, odbc

I have searched a lot for the solution but still struggling with this problem.

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server instance running on 127.0.0.1:1433. However, I'm getting a sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError with the following error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I think I need to install the ODBC driver, but I'm not sure if it needs to be installed on the SQL Server Docker image or on my local VM. If the answer is the Docker image, then I think my /etc/odbcinst.ini file is correctly configured as follows:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

But if the ODBC driver needs to be installed on my local VM, then my /etc/odbcinst.ini file is empty.

Here's the Python code I used to connect to the SQL Server instance:

```bash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = "127.0.0.1,1433"
user = "sa"
password = "Pass@12345"
db_name = "test_database"

engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{server}/{db_name}?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server')

connection = engine.connect()

print("connected")
```

Another question is what should i do if there is `@` in password?

- sqlserver: `sqlserver:2022-latest` docker image, runs on `127.0.0.1:1433`
- os: Ubuntu 22.04
- python: 3.10.6
- sqlalchemy: 2.0.16

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The driver needs to be installed on the device running the code. If you're running that python inside a container, then it needs to be in that container.

Comment: thanks. however it will work on a container but currectly i am working on my local machine.

Comment: Then you need to install the driver on your lcoal machine.

Comment: I have tried to install using ODBC driver 18 as [microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline) but getting error `Unable to locate package msodbcsql18`

Comment: Solved by `sudo apt-get update`. (I have tried it before but due to DNS filtering  it may not have been updated correctly)

Comment: Now getting `Login timeout expired`. I think this is for incorrect connection string which caused by `@` in password.

Comment: *"I have tried to install using ODBC driver 18"* Your error states you are lookign for ODBC 17; 17 <> 18.

Comment: if you believe its due to special characters, can you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423804/writing-a-connection-string-when-password-contains-special-characters ?

Comment: Thanks @python_user. using quote_plus solved `Login timeout`. However `SSL certificate error` raise which solved by using `TrustServerCertificate=yes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by these steps:

##### 1- install ODBC driver on local machine using this script for ubuntu [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline):

```
if ! [[ "18.04 20.04 22.04 22.10" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]];
then
    echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported.";
    exit;
fi

sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

> Note: DNS filtering may cause issues during installation

##### 2- Edit script as bellow to if password contains char `@`

```bash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from urllib.parse import quote_plus


server = "127.0.0.1:1433"
user = "sa"
password = "Pass@12345"
db_name = "test_database"
dsn = "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server"

engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{user}:%s@{server}/{db_name}?TrustServerCertificate=yes&driver={dsn}" % quote_plus(password))

connection = engine.connect()

print("connected")
```

Comment: What are we supposed to do if we are running any of the modern Ubuntu versions?  ("18.04 20.04 22.04 22.10")

Comment: Visit this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Cubuntu16-13-install%2Crhel7-offline#13